# Display an emoji via Skype for Business Chat Bot

Tags: c#, emoji, skype-for-business

We are developing ***chat bot*** using *Microsoft Bot Framework*, which is going to be activated via **Skype for Business**. We tried to display an ***emoji*** through chat bot as followings.

"Please select  Yes   No"

We were success to display emoji but it is not a colored one, ***only black and white image.*** 
I am looking for any suggestions  to ***display colored emoji*** through chat bot?

Answer (score 0):

Try `(y)` and `(n)`, those are the emoticons for  and  in Lync (Skype for Business)